# how can i get this div to stay at the end of the page (not bottom of window)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

on this page (http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com), when the page width is < 900px the footer jumps up towards the top of the page and i want it to stay where it is when the width is > 1000px

CSS

```
#footer {
    font-size: .8em;
    letter-spacing: .128em;
    font-family: "brandon-grotesque",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase ;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #272732;
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0px;    
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding this css attribue "clear:both" ? I think it will solve the issue.

Comment: What about widths between 900 and 1000? I'm assuming the you mean width of less than 900 and more than 900?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving id="end" outside of class="story" then try this css for id="end"

```
bottom: 0;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a media query that is shrinking your content... remove this from your CSS.

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    .header {
        max-height: 600px;
     }
}
```